# Why are structs not allowed in template definitions?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code yields an error `error: ‘struct Foo’ is not a valid type for a template constant parameter`:

```
template <struct Foo>
struct Bar {

};
```

Why is that so?

```
template <class Foo>
struct Bar {

};
```

works perfectly fine and even accepts an struct as argument.

Comment: Because C++ language defined it as such, either `class` or `typename` with `typename` being more descriptive of what is happening from my point of view, otherwise ppl try to replace it with `struct` for some unknown reason ... `template <typename Foo>` means there is a `type` that I will call `Foo` and it will be replaced with the actual type used during compilation ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just an artifact of the syntax rules - the syntax just lets you use the `class` or `typename` keywords to indicate a type template parameter.  Otherwise the parameter has to be a 'non-type' template parameter (basically an integral, pointer or reference type).

I suppose Stroustrup (and whoever else he might have taken input from) decided that there was no need to include `struct` as a a keyword to indicate a type template parameter since there was no need for backwards compatibility with C.

In fact, my recollection <strike>(I'll have to do some book readin' when I get back home)</strike> is that when `typename` was added to indicate a template type parameter, Stroustrup would have liked to take away using the `class` keyword for that purpose (since it was confusing), but there was too much code that relied on it.

---

Edit:

Turns out the story is more like (from a [blog entry by Stan Lippman](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx)):

> The reason for the two keywords is
>   historical. In the original template
>   specification, Stroustrup reused the
>   existing class keyword to specify a
>   type parameter rather than introduce a
>   new keyword that might of course break
>   existing programs. It wasn't that a
>   new keyword wasn't considered -- just
>   that it wasn't considered necessary
>   given its potential disruption. And up
>   until the ISO-C++ standard, this was
>   the only way to declare a type
>   parameter.
>
> Reuses of existing keywords seems to
>   always sow confusion. What we found is
>   that beginners were [wondering]
>   whether the use of the class
>   constrained or limited the type
>   arguments a user could specify to be
>   class types rather than, say, a
>   built-in or pointer type. So, there
>   was some feeling that not having
>   introduced a new keyword was a
>   mistake.
>
> During standardization, certain
>   constructs were discovered within a
>   template definition that resolved to
>   expressions although they were meant
>   to indicate declarations
>
> ...
>
> The committee decided that a new
>   keyword was just the ticket to get the
>   compiler off its unfortunate obsession
>   with expressions. The new keyword was
>   the self-describing typename.
>
> ...
>
> Since the keyword was on the payroll,
>   heck, why not fix the confusion caused
>   by the original decision to reuse the
>   class keyword. Of course, given the
>   extensive body of existing code and
>   books and articles and talks and
>   postings using the class keyword, they
>   chose to also retain support for that
>   use of the keyword as well. So that's
>   why you have both.

Comment: I've been using `template <typename ...>` as long as I can remember, I believe the `class` part confuses people thinking it's the actual `class` and want to stick `struct` in there for some strange reason ...

Comment: At least in his C++0x FAQ (http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html), Stroustrup appears to be using `typename` and `class` in a completely arbitrary way. There's probably no way to avoid the "confusion", because sooner or later you'll run into code that uses `class` (which is just less typing in generally verbose template code, IMO) and you'll have to know that there's no difference anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can instantiate a template using a struct; however, the syntax for declaring a template type only allows the keywords "class" or "typename" to appear where you are attempting to use the keyword "struct".

I should add that you can also use a specific type (e.g. `int`), if you want to instantiate your template based on a compile-time constant or based on an object with external linkage... but that's somewhat of an aside.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: `template <class Foo>` even accepts a `union` or a `double` - still, neither is allowed instead of `class`. However, `typename` is. That's just the way the syntax was defined.

A somewhat longer answer: When templates for C++ where "invented", there was a keyword needed at that place saying that the next identifier would be a type name. It was decided to re-use the existing `class` keyword. That was a bit confusing, but there's a general reluctance to introducing more keywords, because they always break some existing code which used this as an identifier when it wasn't a keyword.

Later, `typename` became a keyword for other reasons, and since it is a much better fit, it can now be used in that place: `template <typename Foo>`. However, with billions of lines of code out there using `class` in that place, it must remain valid for that purpose. So now both are allowed.

As is common in C++, this created several camps as to what keyword to use in that place. Some stick with `class`, because they've been using it for more than a decade. Others prefer `typename`, because it's a much better fit. Some use `class` when `Foo` is expected to be of a `class` type (members are accessed) and `typename` when built-ins can be used, too.

Answer (score 3):

Because the keyword for template parameters is `class` or `typename`. This doesn't restrict the Foo parameter to be a class - it can be of any type.