# Why do both struct and class exist in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct, standards

As we know, `struct` and `class` are interchangeable in many places in the language. Confusingly, the keywords themselves do not necessarily correspond to the language used in the standard. For example, in draft standard N4567 [class]/10,

> A *POD struct*<sup>109</sup> is a non-union class that is both a
>   trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no non-static data
>   members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such
>   types). Similarly, a *POD union* is a union that is both a trivial
>   class and a standard-layout class, and has no non-static data members
>   of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). A *POD
>   class* is a class that is either a POD struct or a POD union.

In over-simplified terms, `struct` and `class` are interchangeable in the following cases:

- declaration of a "class"
- declaration of a scoped enumeration type
- elaborated type specifier unless the "class" was declared with `union`

However, `struct` *explicitly* cannot be used in a template declaration to introduce type template parameters:

```
template <struct T> // error
```

I'm unable to see any significant difference between `struct` and `class`, even in the POD example above because a *POD struct* as defined in the standard can be declared with either `struct` or `class`.

> [class]/8 A *standard-layout struct* is a standard-layout class
>   defined with the *class-key struct* or the *class-key class*. A
>   *standard-layout union* is a standard-layout class defined with the *class-key union*.

This seems rather redundant and confusing while introducing a glaring inconsistency.

I have two questions:

1. Are there any technical differences that I have missed that significantly distinguish `struct` and `class`?
2. What is the rationale, if any, behind this clumsiness?

<sup>I'm ignoring the difference between default access specifiers because everyone knows that already.</sup>

Comment: Does it also puzzle you, that you can have `template<typename T>`, but not `typename T{};`?

Comment: @user2079303 and (before C++1z) `template < template<typename> class C >`, but not `template < template<typename> typename C >`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

Comment: @Martin: No, the OP already knows the differences (he's pointed them all out).

Comment: Can we take the question up a notch and ask if the standard actually prescribes and difference other than the default access? That is, if you had two headers, one of which declared the type as a `struct T` with members and one which declared it as a `class T` with all public members, would both _link_ correctly to an object file that implemented the `T` and the `T::...` members?

Comment: `This seems rather redundant and confusing while introducing a glaring inconsistency.` Could you elaborate on the `inconsistency` that you perceive? It seems perfectly consistent to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why do both struct and class exist in C++?

A reason for existence of `struct` is for compatibility with C.

Why then, did "C with Classes" introduce the new keyword `class` when you could use `struct` for the same thing, you may ask. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1654464/2079303) for plausible speculation. In short, it's probably because there was desire for emphasis on [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in which [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29) is a widely used term. Only Stroustrup may know for certain.

> Confusingly, the keywords themselves do not necessarily correspond to the language used in the standard

What needs to be understood, is that the concept of a *class* is not one and the same with the keyword `class`.

There are three keywords for declaring classes. These keywords known as class-keys are `class`, `struct` and `union`. The non-union classes that are declared with either `class` or `struct` are exactly the same thing, except for <sup>†</sup>. Union classes are different from non-union classes.

> However, struct explicitly cannot be used in a template declaration to introduce type template parameters

C++ re-uses keywords for different purposes in different contexts. `class` keyword in a class declaration context, is not entirely the same as `class` keyword in a template argument definition. One keyword being equivalent to another in one context does not make it equivalent in all contexts. The reason for reusing keywords in different but similar contexts (`static` is another example), is to avoid introducing new keywords, which introduces more holes with compatibility with C (or earlier C++ standard) that does not have the new keywords.

The reason *why* `class` keyword was reused in the context of template type arguments was probably because classes are types, and therefore typically used as type parameters. There is also a `typename` keyword, which was added later and is (almost) interchangeable with `class` in template type argument declaration, but also used elsewhere (dependent type names) where `class` is not used. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213135/2079303) for a link and a summary about why a separate keyword was added to that context.

Why `struct` is not used in the context as an equivalent, you may ask. Well, that's another question to Stroustrup or the committee. It's an opposite choice than what committee did when `enum class`/`enum struct` was introduced.

> I'm unable to see any significant difference between struct and class

Good. There isn't any except for <sup>†</sup>

> This seems rather redundant and confusing while introducing a glaring inconsistency.

I see no inconsistency in the quote from the standard. I see redundancy and I suspect that the redundancy exists to make it extra clear that a class declared with the keyword `struct` is still a class.

> 1. Are there any technical differences that I have missed that significantly distinguish struct and class?

I've already answered, but to be clear, there is **no** difference between classes declared with `struct` and `class` keywords, beyond <sup>†</sup>.

<sup>†</sup> the difference with the default access specifier (as you already know, and also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/999810/2079303)), which is their **only** difference.

Comment: Would there have been any disadvantage to limiting "struct" to PODS declarations, and saying that compilers were under no obligation to treat things declared with "class" as PODs, regardless of content?  I would think that could have made a lot of other rules a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

> Why do both struct and class exist in C++?

`struct` comes from C, and exists in C++ mainly for reasons of compatibility with the C programming language.

> Are there any technical differences that I have missed that
>   significantly distinguish `struct` and `class`?

The main difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that for the `struct` its members have `public` access by default whereas for the `class` its members have `private` access by default.

The keyword `class` used in template arguments does not define a class but rather a non type template argument and can be used interchangeably with keyword `typename`.

As for why you can't use `struct` keyword for specifying a non type template argument, the reasons are historical and I guess you have to ask Bjarne for it :) or refer to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520156/2352671) for info behind the scenes.

Comment: That answers half the question.

Comment: All C programs are valid C++ programs, but not all C++ programs are valid C programs. There is no reason not to allow `template <struct T>` since templates don't exist in C for example.

Comment: @user5817092 `All C programs are valid C++ programs`. **Not** true. A typical example: `int* p = malloc(n * sizeof(int))`

Comment: To be clear, the other half I was referring to (the unanswered half) is about why `class` exists, not the second numbered question.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : i think it's assumed that "complex OOP objects" are expected to be classes, and making all members private by default forces the programmer to think about assigning individual access rights and only expose what's necessary, instead of just going all public

Comment: You mean a type template argument, not a non-type one, right?